# MySQL: Is it mandatory to create a `Unique Key` when you have 2 `Primary Keys` in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key, unique-key

Please pay attention to the below step by step description.

1. I have 2 tables, `Transaction` and `Transaction_Fee`. The `primary key` of `Transaction` is `idTransaction`, which is an auto generated value. The `primary key` of `Transaction_Fee` is `idTransaction_Fee` which is also an auto generated value.
2. Every `Transaction` has a `Transaction_Fee`, therefor, the `idTransaction` is a `foreign key` of `Transaction_Fee` table.
3. Every `Transaction` can have only **one** `Transaction_Fee`

Now, I think I need to make both `idTransaction` and `idTransaction_Fee` as `primary keys` in `Transaction_Fee` table, because `Transaction_Fee` per `Transaction` **cannot** be duplicated.

Now my question is, since the `idTransaction_Fee` is going to have 2 `primary keys`, is it **mandatory** to create a `Unique Key` for `Transaction_Fee` ? The reason I am asking this is in some cases I have seen people creating `Unique Keys` when they have 2 `Primary Keys` in a table. But in my case, since the `Transaction_Fee` can be easily identified using its auto generated ID `idTransaction_Fee`, the `Unique Key` is not required, I think.

However I am willing to take expert advice before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not ever have two primary keys in a single table, you have *one* by definition.

Your requirements seem to be:

- unique ID in the transaction table.
- unique ID in the fee table.
- up to one fee per transaction.

What you do in that case is create primary keys in both tables for their appropriate IDs, this will prevent duplicate IDs in those tables.

Then you need a unique constraint on the `idTransaction` column in the `Transaction_Fee` table. This will prevent two fees belonging to a single transaction by virtue of the fact no two fees can ever have the same transaction ID.

This column should also have a foreign key constraint, referencing `Transaction(idTransaction)`, to ensure it points to a *valid* transaction (i.e., no orphaned fees).

That still allows the possibility of a transaction having *no* fee and there are also ways to ensure the relationship is truly one-to-one in *both* directions if that's what you want (exactly one fee per transaction rather than zero-or-one).

But, in that case, the fee would really seem to be a property of the transaction itself, and should probably go directly into the transaction table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't get your point clearly. You mean make the `idTransaction` a `Unique Key` in `Transaction_Fee` table,  instead of making it a `Primary_Key` too ?

Comment: @Sniper, yes, that's exactly right. You can't _have_ two primary keys in the fees table. I've tried to clear up the answer.

Comment: Thank you. `That still allows the possibility of a transaction having no fee and there are also ways to ensure the relationship is truly one-to-one in both directions if that's what you want ` - Actually the relationship between `Transaction` and `Transaction_Fee` are One-To-One. The `Transaction_Fee` is auto generated using the `After Insert Trigger` of `Transaction`

Comment: @Sniper, if the relationship is one-to-one, then you should consider my final paragraph. It sounds like the fee is an intrinsic property of the transaction in which case 3NF would suggest it go in the same table.

Comment: All of `fee` type things are in a different unique table. For an example, when it comes to `Transaction` it has client id, reference id, comment etc etc so having the fee type things separated is a good way I think. Because `Transaction_Fee` is not just one column table, the fee is divided into various other charges like `service_charge`, `office_charge`, `10% usage charge` etc. all of these are part of `Transaction_Fee`